# No node intellisense in WSL Remote vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Remote WSL in vscode for a simple node.js project. For some reason the `process` variable is not recognized. I installed node on the subsystem, thinking that was the reason, but it didn't help.

[image]

And here is the same line in regular vscode:

[image]